# Can't find module 'stream' (csv-stringify)

Tags: typescript, angular7, tsconfig

I am trying to use csv-stringify module in Angular 7 Typescript project. So I installed it using the

```
npm i csv-stringify --save
```

Then I have imported it in a component class, where I plan to use it, as follows.

```
import * as stringify from 'csv-stringify'
```

However, I am keep getting an error below.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/csv-stringify/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'path-to-project/node_modules/csv-stringify/lib'
```

When I go to index.js mentioned above, the 'stream' actually seems to be part of @angular/types/node. However, in my tsconfig.json I have declared node_modules/@types as typeRoots.

Does anyone have any idea what is the issue here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this problem when using JSZip with angular. You could try the fix that worked for me.

1. Open your `tsconfig.app.json'
2. Add the following

`"paths": {
      "csv-stringify": ["../node_modules/csv-stringify/lib/index.js"]
    }`

to the `compilerOptions` property.

This error mostly occurs when angular can't find the dependency.

Take a look at this issue for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827